# c# inherit dictionary override default property

Tags: c#, inheritance, dictionary

I am trying to make a class that's inherits from Dictionary.

For example:

```
var retDict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
```

then I can call 
retDict["test"] to get the item with key "test".

What I want to do is having a method on retDict that I call like this.
retDict["test","the default return value"];

I want this method to create an item in the base dictionary if the key is not found.

Is this possible? If it is possible, How do I write this method/"peroperty get"?

Best Regards.
/Dennis

[EDIT]

THis is how I write it VB.NET.

Public Class MyDictionary
    Inherits System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)

```
Default Public Overloads Property Item(ByVal key As String, Optional DefaultValue As String = "") As String
    Get
        If Not MyBase.ContainsKey(key) Then
            If DefaultValue <> "" Then
                MyBase.Add(key, DefaultValue)
            Else
                Return ""
            End If
        End If
        Return MyBase.Item(key)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        MyBase.Item(key) = value
    End Set
End Property
```

End Class

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Dictionary` class in the base class library does not directly provide this.  You could use `ConcurrentDictionary<T,U>` instead, which provides a [`GetOrAdd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378676.aspx) method providing this functionality, or implement your own via an extension method.

```
public static U GetOrAdd<T,U>(this Dictionary<T,U> dict, T key, U value)
{
    U val;
    if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out val))
         return val;

    dict[key] = value;
    return value;
}
```

This wouldn't behave as you described - instead you'd do:

```
var val = retDict.GetOrAdd("test", "the default value");
```

The advantage of this approach is it doesn't require creating a custom class (just an extension method) and matches the BCL API (ie: `ConcurrentDictionary<T,U>.GetOrAdd`).

If you want to make a custom class, that can of course be handled via an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx):

```
public TValue this[TKey key, TValue defaultValue]
{
    get
    {
        TValue val;
        if (this.TryGetValue(key, out val))
             return val;

        this[key] = defaultValue;
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have some typos in there Reed. Specifically, you're not returning `val`.. which I assume you meant to.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Thanks for catching it - easy to miss when typing out here ;)

Comment: Yes! It think it's called indexer. ;) I will give it a try. Thank you very much. (PS. I am trying to migrate to C# from long experiense of VB since VB4.0).

Comment: @DennisJohansson I would recomemnd using a method, not an indexer, for this - an indexer suggests (even by its name) that it's retrieving a value based on the "index" you're passing - in this case, what you're passing (default value) is in no way an index.  Using a method makes this more clear.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Yes, I agree. But I want this specific behavior for easy-typing. I am making a universal mini "CMS" thing.

Comment: I start with this line in the Views.
    var CMS = XmasMVC.CMS.EnableCmsParts(ViewBag);
and then
    <h3>@CMS["AsideTitle","Testing Title"]</h3>

Comment: @DennisJohansson Yes - but using `GetOrAdd` instead of an indexer will make your maintenance easier over time ;)  Just a suggestion.

Answer (score -3):

Should be something along the Lines of (coding in browser, so not debugged...)
Not an override really but easy enough to implement...
I'll try turing into a true override later

```
 private string _Value;
    public string GetValue(string KeyName, string sDefault)
    {

        if (_Value.Length == 0)
        {
            return sDefault;
        }
        else
        {
            return sDefault; ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How does this help with a dictionary?

Comment: Trey, additionally to Reed's question, why do you always and only return sDefault? And what happens if _Value == null?

Comment: Sorry fat fingered that one, and good point on the dictionary.